# TS2307 Error: Cannot find module '../constants' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am currently getting the error while trying to import. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**tabs.tsx | src>navigation>tabs.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native'
import {createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar} from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"
import {icons} from '../constants'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
```

**Structure**

[image]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es2017"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    "isolatedModules": true,                  /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
  
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": false,                    /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true                 /* Allows importing modules with a ‘.json’ extension, which is a common practice in node projects. */

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you there's nothing to `import` from the location it's currently pointed at.

`import`-ing from a folder actually looks for a `index.[d.](t|j)s` file in that folder. If that file exists and it has a default export, you can assign the export a name in local scope, at import:

```
import stuff from '../constants'
```

If it contains named exports you can import them using brackets:

```
import { myExport } from '../constants' //or 
import { myExport as localName } from '../constants'
```

Note: the above implies your `index.ts` contains something like:

```
export const myExport = (/* some expression */)
// you can export types, consts, functions, classes, interfaces, etc...
```

If you want to import all named exports from that file, use `*`:

```
import * from '../constants' // myExport is now usable
// or namespaced:
import * as local from '../constants' // (and use as local.myExport)
```

More examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).
Spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-imports).

If you placed a file named `icons.ts`, having a default export, in `/constants` folder, your import should look like this:

```
import icons from '../constants/icons'
// or, for a named export
import { icons } from '../constants/icons'
```

Answer (score 0):

create index.ts in folder constants and added next constants for example:

```
export * from './icons';
...
export * from './common';
```

in icons module defined next:

```
export const icons = [{...},{...}]; // or another entity for example {}
```

that is pattern - **barrel**, in other modules just import neccesary constants:

```
import { icons } from '../constants';
```